# next() and prev() position with array function php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code below,

```
<?php
$people = array("patrick", "wumbo", "wambo", "Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");

echo current($people) . "<br>";
echo next($people) . "<br>";
echo prev($people);
?>
```

my question is if I want current position is "joe", how to show my all previous position and my all next position ?

output:

```
my prev = *patrick wumbo wambo Peter*

my next = *Glenn Cleveland*
```

#### **update question**

```
<?php
$a = "My brother see the moon";
$b = explode(" ",preg_replace("/(\.|\"|,|;|\(|\)|'|)+?/i","",$a));
for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
            {
            $huruf_kecil = strtolower($a);
            $fungsi_replace = preg_replace("/(\.|\"|,|;|\(|\)|'|)+?/i","",$huruf_kecil);
            $pecah_untuk_kata = explode(" ",$fungsi_replace);
            $pecah_kata = $pecah_untuk_kata[$ulangKata];
            echo "kata ke - ".$ulangKata." ".$b[$ulangKata]."<br>"; 
            }
            echo "<br>";
            for($ulangKata=0;$ulangKata<count($b);$ulangKata++)
            {
            echo $b[$ulangKata]."<br>";
            }
?>
```

and I want see the output like

```
Subject : My brother
Predicate : see
Object : the moon
```

I have already trying but have no idea since last night.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
    $current= "Joe";

    $people = array("patrick", "wumbo", "wambo", "Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");
    $pos    = array_search($current, $people);

    foreach($people as $key => $value) {

        if($key < $pos) {

            $prev[] = $value;

        } elseif($key > $pos) {

            $next[] = $value;

        }

    }

    foreach($prev as $item) {
        echo "$item ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
    foreach($next as $item) {
        echo "$item ";
    }
```

**Output**:

```
patrick wumbo wambo Peter 
Glenn Cleveland
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
<?php

        function getSubObj($string, $verb) {

            $parts  = explode(" ", $string);
            $pos    = array_search($verb, $parts);

            foreach($parts as $key => $value) {

                if($key < $pos) {

                    $subjects[] = $value;

                } elseif($key > $pos) {

                    $objects[]  = $value;

                }

            }

            return array($subjects, $objects);

        }

        list($subjects, $objects) = getSubObj("Brother see the moon", "see");

        echo "<h2>Subjects</h2>";
        foreach($subjects as $item) {
            echo "$item ";
        }

        echo "<h2>Objects</h2>";
        foreach($objects as $item) {
            echo "$item ";
        }


?>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank's Emil, But can I Show the Array without print_r ? just like echo.

Comment: Ya, It work for me, I have a question about my code, $text="Brother See the moon"; can I use code above ?

Comment: Hi Emil, can I explode "Brother see the moon" with for loop ?

Comment: Hi! Why would you use a for loop? Just use explode() as in my example.

Comment: Hi Emil, my code it's too complicated, Can I explain via email ?

Comment: Update your question and explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

make it easy by array_slice

```
$key=array_search("Joe",$people);
echo "Current:".$people[$key] . "\n" .
     "Prev:".implode(",", array_slice($people, 0, $key)) . "\n" .
     "Next:".implode(",", array_slice($people, $key+1));
```

Comment: Thank's splash58 to help me, I'll notify you again to applicate above in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<?php
$people = array("patrick", "wumbo", "wambo", "Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");


$key=array_search("Joe",$people);
$next=array();
$prev=array();
for($i=$key+1;$i<count($people);$i++)
{
$next[]=$people[$i];
}

for($i=$key-1;$i >0;$i--)
{
$prev[]=$people[$i];
}

echo "Current:".$people[$key];
 echo "</br>";
echo "Next:".implode(",",$next);
 echo "</br>";
echo "prev:".implode(",",$prev);
?>
```

Result:

```
Current:Joe
Next:Glenn,Cleveland
prev:Peter,wambo wumbo
```

Comment: Thank's Deena for your guide, my code was complicated, but I just can explain the code like this, hope it helpful to me. I'll be right back to notify you again with my result. Regard's

Comment: Hi Deena, I have a question 

Hmm if I have a String like, 

$text = "Brother see the moon"; 

I sign to my code that "see" as verb, 

all array before "see" as subject 

and all array after "see" as object how to use next() and prev() to my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's all for your support,

Hmm if I have a String like  below

```
$text = "Brother see the moon";
```

I sign to my code that "see" as **verb**,

all array before "see" as **subject**

and all array after "see" as **object**